# RevMobAds HideBanner

Tags: ios, objective-c, revmob

This is my first time using RevMob but it seemed like it should be simple enough, however I'm having a hard time hiding banner ads.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(IBAction)startGame:(id)sender
{
    [[RevMobAds session] hideBanner];
}
```

When the view loads the banner is there on the bottom, but when I call the function startGame (via a button in the same view) it doesn't go away, the banner remains.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same issue, I was able to get it working with the following:

```
RevMobBanner* banner;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];
    banner = [[RevMobAds session] banner];
    [banner showAd];
} 

-(IBAction)startGame:(id)sender
{
    [banner hideAd];
}
```

I think they may have deprecated the docs listed on their website (always awesome) so hopefully this helps someone.